# How can I cure my red eared slider from fungus infection

Tags: turtles

I have been noticing some white spots on my red eared slider’s shell and I researched about it and it turned out to be a fungus infection. How can I treat my turtle without the help of a vet? [image]

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the vet? The vet is the first person to go to if the animal is ill... How does it goes with your turtle? Maybe your experience helps other people if you answer your own question.